# Ubuntu 15.04 wont detect Second core

Tags: dell

I am a big fan of Ubuntu Operating system however I have encountered a strange problem. My Dell presicion 360 workstation wont detect the second core. I run the Grep cores /proc/cpuinfo command and I only get one core. I am running A dual core intel Pentium 4 CPU @ 2.8 GHz. Does anyone have a solution to this problem.

Comment: Please install a supported Ubuntu release.

Comment: Should I download and install Ubuntu 15.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu doesn't detect a second core of your Pentium 4 CPU because Pentium 4 processors are single core CPUs only, not dual core CPUs. According to the [Wikipedia Pentium 4 article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_4):

> Pentium 4 is a line of single-core desktop, laptop and entry level server central processing units (CPUs) introduced by Intel on November 20, 2000 and shipped through August 8, 2008.

The dual core variant of the Pentium 4 "Prescott" processor manufactured by Intel from 2005 to 2008 was called the Pentium D.

Comment: but I do think its a dual core because it supports hyperthreading

Comment: Oh well you are right it only has one core. thank you for the answer

Comment: Some Pentium 4 CPUs do support hyperthreading. For example: [Intel® Pentium® 4 Processor 630 supporting HT Technology
(2M Cache, 3.00 GHz, 800 MHz FSB)](http://ark.intel.com/products/27478/Intel-Pentium-4-Processor-630-supporting-HT-Technology-2M-Cache-3_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB).

Comment: Thank you karel, I will hopefully upgrade computer later on or upgrade this current one .